# Adding Comma's to Strings in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create a formula to add a comma after the 2nd string if there are more name than two and otherwise add a comma after first string.
But my formula is just adding the comma after first string.

My formula:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",", ",1)`

My strings:

Strings

```
ARISMEL SANTOS ROSARIO
ADREMIR J GAMBOA ORTIZ
  LOGAN NOVA HERNANDEZ MEJIA LACAYO
    ADREMIR J HERNANDEZ MEJIA
   AVERY GRAN
```

My unwanted result is:

```
ARISMEL, SANTOS ROSARIO
ADREMIR J, GAMBOA ORTIZ
LOGAN NOVA, HERNANDEZ MEJIA LACAYO
ADREMIR J, HERNANDEZ MEJIA
AVERY, GRANT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming cell A1 has any of the example name you provided.

Put the following formula in B1 -> `=LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", ""))`
and the formula in C1 -> `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",", ",IF(B1<=2,1,2))`

It is good to have trimmed text (which I have done in formula) to begin with.

See if this helps.

Edit: If you want to do it in a single formula, `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",", ",IF((LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", ""))) <=2,1,2))`